# Spring-kafka and kafka 0.10

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently trying to use kafka and spring-kafka in order to consumer messages.

But I have trouble executing several consumers for the same topic and have several questions:

**1 - My consumers tends to disconnect after some time and have trouble reconnecting**

The following WARN is raised regularly on my consumers:

```
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] f.b.poc.crawler.kafka.KafkaListener      : Consuming {"some-stuff": "yes"} from topic [job15]
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] f.b.p.c.w.services.impl.CrawlingService  : Start of crawling
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] f.b.p.c.w.services.impl.CrawlingService  : Url has already been treated ==> skipping
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  WARN 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Auto-commit of offsets {job15-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=11547, metadata=''}, job15-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15550, metadata=''}} failed for group group-3: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [job15-3, job15-2] for group group-3
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] s.k.l.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer : partitions revoked:[job15-3, job15-2]
2017-09-06 15:32:35.054  INFO 5203 --- [nListener-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group group-3
```

This cause the consumer to stop and wait for several seconds.

As mentionned in the message, I increased the consumers `session.timeout.ms` to something like `30000`. I still get the message.
As you can see in the provided logs the disconnection occurs right after a record has finished its process.
So ... a lot before 30s of innactivity.

**2- Two consumers application receives the same message REALLY often**

While looking at my consumers' logs I saw that they tend to treat the same message. I understood Kafka is `at-least-once` but I never thought I would encounter a lot of duplication.
Hopefully I use redis but I probably have missunderstood some tuning / properties I need to do.

**THE CODE**

**Note:** I'm using `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` with `auto-commit=true` but run with 1 Thread. I just start several instances of the same application because the consumer uses services that aren't thread-safe.

***KafkaContext.java***

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = KafkaConfig.class)
class KafkaContext {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer kafkaInListener(IKafkaListener listener, KafkaConfig config) {
        final ContainerProperties containerProperties =
                new ContainerProperties(config.getIn().getTopic());
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(listener);
        final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> defaultKafkaConsumerFactory =
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(config));

        final ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer =
                new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(defaultKafkaConsumerFactory, containerProperties);

        messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(config.getConcurrency());
        messageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(KafkaConfig config) {
        final String kafkaHost = config.getHost() + ":" + config.getPort();
        log.info("Crawler_Worker connecting to kafka at {} with consumerGroup {}", kafkaHost, config.getIn().getGroupId());
        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaHost);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, config.getIn().getGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JacksonNextSerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        return props;
    }

}
```

***Listener***

```
@Slf4j
@Component
class KafkaListener implements IKafkaListener {

    private final ICrawlingService crawlingService;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaListener(ICrawlingService crawlingService) {
        this.crawlingService = crawlingService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, Next> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("Consuming {} from topic [{}]", JSONObject.wrap(consumerRecord.value()), consumerRecord.topic());

        consumerService.apply(consumerRecord.value());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that your consumer group is continuously being rebalanced. You are right about increasing `session.timeout.ms`, but I don't see this config applied in your configuration. Try removing:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
```

and setting:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
```

You can increase `MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG` to get a better performance on communication with brokers. But if you process messages in one thread only it is safer to keep this value low.

Comment: Hi, Well sometimes someone has to look to your code ... Thank you pointing out I've chosen the wrong parameter.. I'll try this today and keep this issue updated !